# Modifying/debugging frozen builtins like importlib/_boostrap_external.py

Tags: python, debugging, built-in, python-internals

**Short version**: How do I debug frozen libs? Can I tell Python not to use them (and use sourcefiles) or re-freeze them some how?

---

I'm trying to learn more about the inner functionality of pythons import mechanisms. And by going down that rabbit hole, I want to debug `/usr/lib/python37/importlib/_bootstrap_external.py`.

Using `python -m trace --trace myscript.py` gave me indications of where in `_bootstrap_external.py` I am landing, but not values. So I turned to `pdb` and it gave me a bit of information but appears to be skipping `_frozen` objects. (?).

So I added a few `print('moo')` where I saw my script ending up in `_boostrap_external.py` but no prints are ever made, because Python internally uses `<class '_frozen_importlib_external.PathFinder'>`

That lead me in a desperate attempt to try and renaming/removing `/usr/lib/python37/importlib/__pycache__` in a hope that Python would re-compile my changes. But no such luck, Python still uses a frozen version.

So I modified `/usr/lib/python37/__init__.py` where it imports the `_bootstrap` module, so I changed this:

```py
try:
    import _frozen_importlib_external as _bootstrap_external
except ImportError:
    from . import _bootstrap_external
    _bootstrap_external._setup(_bootstrap)
    _bootstrap._bootstrap_external = _bootstrap_external
else:
    _bootstrap_external.__name__ = 'importlib._bootstrap_external'
    _bootstrap_external.__package__ = 'importlib'
    try:
        _bootstrap_external.__file__ = __file__.replace('__init__.py', '_bootstrap_external.py')
    except NameError:
        # __file__ is not guaranteed to be defined, e.g. if this code gets
        # frozen by a tool like cx_Freeze.
        pass
    sys.modules['importlib._bootstrap_external'] = _bootstrap_external
```

to this:

```py
from . import _bootstrap_external
_bootstrap_external._setup(_bootstrap)
_bootstrap._bootstrap_external = _bootstrap_external
_bootstrap_external.__name__ = 'importlib._bootstrap_external'
_bootstrap_external.__package__ = 'importlib'
try:
    _bootstrap_external.__file__ = __file__.replace('__init__.py', '_bootstrap_external.py')
except NameError:
    # __file__ is not guaranteed to be defined, e.g. if this code gets
    # frozen by a tool like cx_Freeze.
    pass
sys.modules['importlib._bootstrap_external'] = _bootstrap_external
```

And that worked, ish. Obviously the problem will become more and more complex, and there has to be a more generic solution. But I continued my journey and found that `_bootstrap.py` is indeed loaded with my `print('moo')` changes. But when `/usr/lib/python37/importlib/_bootstrap.py` later calls the function `_find_spec`, and it does:

```py
    for finder in meta_path:
        with _ImportLockContext():
            find_spec = finder.find_spec
            spec = find_spec(name, path, target)
```

`find_spec` will refer to the frozen version again. *(Code snippet shortened to the relevant code in `_bootstrap.py`)*

So my question finally ends up in, how do I debug these frozen files? or how do I make it so Python ignores frozen libraries (I can take the performance impact when debugging). Every attempt to find information on this (searching, docs, irc, etc) ends up on "why?" or "don't do this" or it points me to `py2exe` and how to freeze my libraries. I just want to be able to debug and understand more of how the inner mechanics work by trying things and looking at the variables.

Comment: Just to add more confusion: I am trying to fix a bug in a frozen builtin module `zipimport`. The bug (missing 't'  when calling `_bootstrap_external._validate_hash_pyc`)  is already fixed upstream (see https://bugs.python.org/issue39033), but the fix has not yet propagated to Arch Linux package. So I fixed  `zipimport.py` in python sources myself and rebuilt the whole python-3.8 Arch package and installed it. Still, using zipimport fails with the same bug (NameError: name '_boostrap_external' is not defined). So I am totally confused: From where are these frozen built-in modules loaded?